# Java Swing : Alt-tab styled menu (context switching menu)

Tags: java, swing, menu, window, switch-statement

### Are there any current implementations or frameworks for Java Swing that include functionality for a context-switcher menu?

---

More detail:

In our application, we have several sub-parts of the application, and only one of them is displayed at once. Presently there are several ways to switch between them, including tool bar buttons and via the `View` menu. We would like to add another means, that is accessible via a keyboard shortcut. This would bring up a context-switch menu, similar in concept to those available in modern OS'es.

If you press `Alt+Tab` and release the `Tab` while still holding down `Alt`, you will get a little window in the middle of the screen, displaying the various applications that are running at the moment. In Ubuntu, you get a screenshot of each application, plus its window manager icon. In Windows you get the window  manager icons, and so on.

[image]

Comment: Are you looking for something like menu shortcuts? - http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/AddingMenuShortcuts.htm

Comment: @bancer : Nope, my menus already make use of implementations of `AbstractAction`, so keyboard shortcuts are not the main requirement - that would be the actual context-switching menu.

Comment: @bancer : added scr shot to show what i mean.

Comment: Do you have several JFrames that you want to switch around?

Comment: @bancer : Just one `JFrame`, and it shows different panels depednign on the context.

Comment: alt-tab is an OS thing that allows you to change applications. I doubt that you really want to short-circuit an OS mnemonic.

Comment: @Hovercraft : I do not want to use the exact keystroke combination `alt+tab`, any other reasonable keyboard shortcut will do. My real intent of this question was really a means to get the context switcher menu, such as the one appearing in the screen shot above, in a Java Swing application.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is possible.  You could apply a transformation to a `Graphics` option that you pass to each `JFrame` and have it paint a small version of itself on it.  Then take those images and place them on a `GlassPane` on top of your application.   The highlighting of the selected window might be tricky, but I think it would work nicely.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - so I take it that you know of no frameworks that currently achieve this? Just checking because I don't want to have to write code from scratch if it already exists!

Comment: @bguiz, yes, I have no knowledge of a framework that accomplishes this.  (That doesn't mean it is not worth searching for just in case).